# C++ Compiler allows circular definition?

Tags: c++, c++14

I ran into the following oddity when making a mistake writing some code for trees. I've stripped down this example a lot so it is only a Linear Tree.

Basically, in the main() function, I wanted to attach a Node to my tree, but instead of attaching it to "tree.root", I attached it to just "root". However, to my surprise, not only did it all compile just fine, but *I was able to call methods on the nodes*. It only errored when I tried to access the "value" member variable.

I guess my main question is, why didn't the compiler catch this bug?

```
std::shared_ptr<Node> root = tree.AddLeaf(12, root);
```

Since "root" on the RHS is a flat-out undeclared variable. Also, out of curiosity, if the compiler lets them through, do circular definitions have an actual use case? Here's the rest of the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Node
{
    int value;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> child;

    Node(int value)
    : value {value}, child {nullptr} {}

    int SubtreeDepth()
    {
        int current_depth = 1;
        if(child != nullptr) return current_depth + child->SubtreeDepth();
        return current_depth;
    }
};

struct Tree
{
    std::shared_ptr<Node> root;

    std::shared_ptr<Node> AddLeaf(int value, std::shared_ptr<Node>& ptr)
    {
        if(ptr == nullptr)
        {
            ptr = std::move(std::make_shared<Node>(value));
            return ptr;
        }
        else
        {
            std::shared_ptr<Node> newLeaf = std::make_shared<Node>(value);
            ptr->child = std::move(newLeaf);
            return ptr->child;
        }
    }
};


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

    Tree tree;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> root = tree.AddLeaf(12, root);
    std::shared_ptr<Node> child = tree.AddLeaf(16, root);

    std::cout << "root->SubtreeDepth() = " << root->SubtreeDepth() << std::endl; 
    std::cout << "child->SubtreeDepth() = " << child->SubtreeDepth() << std::endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
root->SubtreeDepth() = 2
child->SubtreeDepth() = 1
```

Comment: `int x = x + 1;` what bug? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: First the variable is initialized (int std::shared_ptr's case with null pointer), then the assignment is performed. Try using a constructor and it will not be allowed.

Comment: @rkapl no, the variable is not initialized in this case until RHS completes. This statement is known as [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization).

Comment: @Ruslan -- you are right, thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That's an unfortunate side-effect of definitions in C++, that declaration and definition is done as separate steps. Because the variables are *declared* first, they can be used in their own initialization:

```
std::shared_ptr<Node> root = tree.AddLeaf(12, root);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Declaration of the variable  Initialization clause of variable
```

Once the variable is declared, it can be used in the initialization for the full definition of itself.

It will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in `AddLeaf` if the data of the second argument is used, as the variable is not initialized.

Comment: In this case - the default constructor of root would be called first; then addLeaf; then equals operator.  I don't think there's any UB here.

Comment: @UKMonkey Note that this isn't assignment, but copy-construction (or rather [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization)). The definition is equal to `std::shared_ptr<Node> root(tree.AddLeaf(12, root));` The default constructor will not be called.

Comment: You're right - UB can also include using default constructor .... silly me.

Comment: @UKMonkey: While some forms of UB can happen in the presence of the default constructor, the particular form used here (object defined used in as argument in its own initialization) can not involve the default constructor because that _by definition_  does not take arguments.

Comment: @MSalters SomeProgrammerDude explained it better.  Your suggestion is that the default constructor here can't be used; but it can... it wouldn't be a very efficient compiler in retrospect, but it certainly wouldn't be invalid.

Comment: @UKMonkey: Compilers have no choice in this matter. The Standard strictly defines overload resolution for constructors, and the number of arguments alone rules out the default constructor. Efficiency is not a factor in that.

Comment: It only leads to undefined behavior if the variable is *read* from or *written* to.  If its address or identity is stored but the value of the variable is never read from or written to, no UB occurs.  It is, however, very fragile.

Comment: At least in C (can't think of any good reason in c++ though except the original compatibility with c) there's good reason for having definition and declaration separately though: `Foo *foo = malloc(sizeof(*foo));` is a common idiom and avoids common pitfalls when refactoring code.

Answer (score 13):

> Since "root" on the RHS is a flat-out undeclared variable.

It's not undeclared. It is declared by that very same statement. However, `root` *is* uninitialised at the point where `AddLeaf(root)` is called, so when the value of the object is used (compared to null etc.) within the function, the behaviour is undefined.

Yes, using a variable in its own declaration is allowed, but using its value is not. Pretty much all you can do with it is take the address or create a reference, or expressions that only deal with type of the sub expression such as `sizeof` and `alignof`.

Yes, there are use cases although they may be rare. For example, you might want to represent a graph, and you might have a constructor for node that takes a pointer to linked node as an argument and you might want to be able to represent a node that links with itself. Thus you might write `Node n(&n)`. I won't argue whether that would be a good design for a graph API.

Comment: Recursive lambda is more reasonable use case: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c4693c645d76d34