# Why sizeof succeeds on not yet exsisting variable?

Tags: c, esp32

Today I had troubles with corrupted heap on ESP32. As it turned out, bug was caused by this line:

```
u8x8_i2c_cmdinfo* cmdinfo = malloc(sizeof(cmdinfo));
```

When I meant

```
u8x8_i2c_cmdinfo* cmdinfo = malloc(sizeof(u8x8_i2c_cmdinfo));
```

It actually surpriszed me a lot that wrong version compiled at all.

Why do it work? What it actually does?

Comment: Because `sizeof(cmdinfo)` is the size of a pointer, not what it is pointing to.

Comment: While [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54073039/c-compiler-allows-circular-definition/54073138#54073138) is for a C++ question, it might still be helpful in understanding what's happening.

Comment: `u8x8_i2c_cmdinfo* cmdinfo = malloc(sizeof(cmdinfo));` is a declaration (`u8x8_i2c_cmdinfo* cmdinfo;`) followed by an initialization (`cmdinfo = malloc(sizeof(cmdinfo));`) combined in the same line. At initialization time, the variable was already declared.

Comment: The more idiomatic way to do this malloc indeed makes use of the fact that the variable already exists: `type * pointer = malloc((sizeof (*pointer)) * num)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code compiles because variable exists after its declaration. And this part just declared it: `u8x8_i2c_cmdinfo* cmdinfo`.

You wouldn't be surprised if that worked, right?

```
u8x8_i2c_cmdinfo* cmdinfo;
cmdinfo = malloc(sizeof(cmdinfo));
```

Keep in mind, that while your code compiles fine, it has a nasty bug. You are allocating space for the size of the pointer, most likely not what you want to do.

Comment: FWIW, `cmdinfo = malloc(sizeof(cmdinfo));` is almost always wrong. I think you probably mean `cmdinfo = malloc(sizeof(*cmdinfo));`.

Comment: @CarlNorum nope, this is exactly what I meant, because this is the code OP has written - I was illustrating it with equivalent code. And I mention that this is a bug, although it compiles.